# ReactJS DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`categoryInfo` is an array of objects. When calling the API `readRelationById` it reloads the array of objects if something is added or deleted in the database. I get an error when added a new object or removing it from the list.

```
getInfo = id => {
  Api.readRelationById(id)
    .then(res => this.setState({ categoryInfo: res }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

How the list is rendering:

```
<select
  multiple
  onChange={onRemoveChange(props)}
  size="10"
  style={{ width: "500px" }}
>
  {props.categoryInfo !== undefined ? (
    props.categoryInfo.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <option value={item.id} key={index}>
          {item.id} {item.description}
        </option>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <option disabled> N/A </option>
  )}
</select>;
```

Error message:

> NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node
>   before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this
>   node.

RemoveChange

```
const onRemoveChange = (props) => (e) => {
    let options = e.target.options;
    let value = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            value.push(options[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(value);
    props.onListClick(value);
};
```

```
    onListClick = (values) => {
        this.setState({removeList: values});
    };
```

Comment: Could you include how `onRemoveChange` is defined?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `key={item.id}` instead of `key={index}`? If not, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.